# Cascading text formatting for theatre

Tags: formatting

I'm currently writing a play with the sides environment.
As I'm writing in alexandrine, each line shall consist of exactly 12 feet.
When several characters talk, indents are necessary to show I'm not finishing a verse, but completing it to 12 feet. I'm currently using a fixed indent.
Speakers are indicated here as sections.

```
\section*{First Guard}
You are not welcome here!
\section*{First Beggar}
\hspace{25mm}Let me in! 
\section*{Second Beggar}
\hspace{50mm}Let me in!
```

With the following result:

[image: fixed indentation]

How can I format my text so that each reply is in the continuity of the previous one? As if it was one sentence cascading over several lines?

This is what I'm looking for:

[image: cascading alexandrine]

Answer (score 2):

You could use `\phantom`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section*{First Guard}
You are not welcome here!
\section*{First Beggar}
\phantom{You are not welcome here! }Let me in! 
\section*{Second Beggar}
\phantom{You are not welcome here! Let me in! }Let me in!
\end{document}
```

[image]